# how to create field alias

Tags: oracle

I've heared that it could be possible to create an alias for a field using Oracle views, is that really possible? can you show a simple example ?

p.s. I need an alias for each field in my table for some reason regarding my application.
thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want this alias to look like?

Comment: Give your current table strcture, some sample data, and an idea what you want to be able to get out.

Answer (score 2):

You say your requirement is to alias each "cell" (row/column intersection) in a table - the the answer is **no**, that is not possible.  But perhaps if you explain more about what you are actually trying to achieve there will be an alternative.  For example, in an **application** you can certainly assign a unique ID to each field.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is what you are looking for. **You can alias a field in a SELECT statement**, so that the returned results use the alias for the field name instead of the name as it appears in the table or view.

You do it like this:

```
SELECT employee_id "Employee ID number", last_name "Employee last name", 
first_name "Employee first name" FROM employees;
```

The aliases are the values in quotes. So, for example, "`Employee ID number`" is the alias for the field `employee_id`.

The aliases are contained in double quotes here because of the spaces in them.

These aliases are not saved anywhere in the database. You have to create them in your SQL statement each time.

But they solve the problem of naming the fields the way you want when you return the results to the application.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I need the an alias on each field not on column level (i.e. in the schema browser in TOAD application, i need an alias for each cell on a specific table), did you get the question ?